# Magento multi select attribute - wont show on front-end if only 1 option selected for product

Tags: php, magento, attributes, multi-select

Having an issue with displaying multi-select attribute options: 
the following code used in catalog/product/list.phtml works perfectly to display the selected attributes - but only if MORE THAN ONE option is selected - 
so if only one option from the multi select attribute is selected it doesn't display anything?

```
<?php
$targetValues = $_product->getAttributeText('ni_featured_logo_multi');
foreach($targetValues as $_target) :?>
<div class="featuredlogolist">
<span class="helper"></span>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>FEATURED_LOGOS/<?php echo $_target ?>.png" class="featuredlogo"></img>
</div>
<?php endforeach;
?>
```

This is true for for the product page as well ( code used in catalog/product/view.phtml )

```
 <?php
   $multiSelectArray = $this->getProduct ()->getAttributeText('ni_featured_logo_multi');
   $lastItem = end ($multiSelectArray);
   foreach ($multiSelectArray as $multiSelectItem) :?>
   <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>FEATURED_LOGOS/<?php echo $multiSelectItem ?>.png" class="featuredlogo"></img>
   <?php endforeach;
 ?>
```

any ideas on how to adjust call in order to have the multi select attribute display when only 1 option is selected ? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `getAttributeText()` actually returns an array only if there is more than one option, otherwise it just returns the single option as a string literal. I think the method declaration is actually wrong here, but I can confirm that this is the behavior from experience.

You should add a simple check like this:

```
if ($targetValues = $_product->getAttributeText('ni_featured_logo_multi')) {
    if (is_string($targetValues)) {
        $targetValues = array($targetValues);
    }
    foreach ($targetValues as $_target) ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! - cant get that code to work ? could you elaborate on how to use it on the product and product list? thanks for the help

Comment: @chrismmmmm - What happens if you `var_dump($targetValues)` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

wanted to post the working code - with edit from fantasticrice: 
multi select in catalog/product/list.phtml: ( this is getting an image name from skin folder )

```
 <?php if ($targetValues = $_product->getAttributeText('your_attribute_code')) {
    if (is_string($targetValues)) {
        $targetValues = array($targetValues);
    }
        foreach($targetValues as $_target) :?>
         <div class="featuredlogo">
         <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>FEATURED_LOGOS/<?php echo $_target ?>.png" class="featuredlogo"></img>
         </div>
        <?php endforeach;
                 }
    ?>
```

and here in catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
  <?php
    if ($multiSelectArray = $this->getProduct ()->getAttributeText('your_attribute_code')) {
    if (is_string($multiSelectArray)) {
        $multiSelectArray = array($multiSelectArray);
    }
    foreach ($multiSelectArray as $multiSelectItem) :?>
   <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>FEATURED_LOGOS/<?php echo $multiSelectItem ?>.png" class="featuredlogo"></img>
   <?php endforeach;

                    }
    ?>
```

thanks fantasticrice!